# Many To Many (Polymorphic) using the same model with different types

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have these 3 tables in the database:
[image: Database]

I'm using Many To Many (Polymorphic) Eloquent relationship to connect the Models. The problem is that the `Creadores` table can be of type `artista` or `autor` in the `Creaciones` table. 
Is it possible to tell Eloquent when to use `artista` or `autor`?

It works if I extend the `Creador` Model into 2 other Models: `Artista` and `Autor`. But when I want to show all the `creaciones` of a `creador` using the `Creador` Model, it's not possible because the Polymorphic relationship was created with the extended models.

Libro Model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use ChrisKonnertz\BBCode\BBCode;

class Libro extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Libros';

    // Return all the artists of the book
    public function artistas()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Creador', 'creador', 'creaciones');
    }

    // Return all the authors of the book
    public function autores()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Creador', 'creador', 'creaciones');
    }
}
```

Creador Model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Creador extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'creators';

    // Return all the books where author
    public function autorLibros()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Libro', 'creador', 'creaciones');
    }

    // Return all the books where artist
    public function artistaLibros()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Libro', 'creador', 'creaciones');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it the following way. Changed the relation from a Polymorphic Many to Many to a normal Many to Many, adding `withPivot` and `wherePivot`.

Creador Model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Creador extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'creators';

    public function libros()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Libro', 'creaciones')->withPivot('creador_type');
    }

    // All books as an Artist
    public function librosArtista()
    {
        return $this->libros()->wherePivot('creador_type', 1);
    }

    // All books as an Author
    public function librosAutor()
    {
        return $this->libros()->wherePivot('creador_type', 2);
    }
}
```

Libro Model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use ChrisKonnertz\BBCode\BBCode;

class Libro extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'libros';

    public function creador()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Creador', 'creaciones')->withPivot('creador_type');
    }

    // All book artists
    public function artistas()
    {
        return $this->creador()->wherePivot('creador_type', 1);
    }

    // All book authors
    public function autores()
    {
        return $this->creador()->wherePivot('creador_type', 2);
    }
}
```

And when creating a attaching a `Creador` to a `Libro`:

```php
$libro->artistas()->attach( $creador, [
    'creador_type' => 1
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off just adding a `type` property to `Creador` with `'artista'`/`'autor'` in it.

The polymorphic relationship can only take a single model.
So your code would then become:

```php
public function creadors()
{
    // Return a general relation for all 'creadores'.
    return $this->morphedByMany(App\Creador::class, 'creador', 'creaciones');
}

public function artistas()
{
    // Filter for 'artista's.
    return $this->creadors()->where('type', 'artista');
}

public function autores()
{
    // Filter for 'autor's.
    return $this->creadors()->where('type', 'autor');
}
```

Comment: If I add a `type` attribute, how would i add it when relating the models using attach() ? `$libro->autores()->attach( $creador );`

Comment: calling `attach` on that relation will not do anything with `type` so you'll have to manually set the `type` property for that `$creador` instance.